# How can I get the second part of a hyphenated word using regex?

Tags: regex

For example, I have the word: `sh0rt-t3rm`.
How can I get the `t3rm` part using perl regex?

I could get `sh0rt` by using `[(a-zA-Z0-9)+]\[-\]`, but `\[-\][(a-zA-Z0-9)+]` doesn't work to get `t3rm`.

Comment: Both patterns don't work to get any of those parts. The character class notation is like this `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` and then getting the group value like this `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-` So to get both `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` Or just one `-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax used for the regex is not correct to get either `sh0rt` or `t3rm`

You flipped the square brackets and the parenthesis, and the hyphen does not have to be between square brackets.

To get `sh0rt` in `sh0rt-t3rm` you you might use for example one of:

| Regex | Demo | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` \b([a-zA-Z0-9]+)- ``` | [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/ovdmPF/1) | `\b` is a word boundary to prevent a partial word match, the value is in capture group 1. |
| ``` \b[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=-) ``` | [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/3ldIBg/1) | Match the allowed chars in the character class, and assert a `-` to the right using a positive lookahead `(?=-)` |

To get `t3rm` in `sh0rt-t3rm` you might use for example one of:

| Regex | Demo | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` -([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b ``` | [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/wviSR1/1) | The other way around with a leading `-` and get the value from capture group 1. |
| ``` -\K[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b ``` | [Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/eZkqUr/1) | Match `-` and use `\K` to keep out what is matched so far. Then match 1 or more times the allowed chars in the character class. |

Comment: Oh, how nicely formatted! !!

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks, I was just trying out some of the options..my best artwork ever :-)

Comment: Artwork indeed!  I was just viewing your src and digging into meta how this works.

Comment: you guys are wholesome @bobblebubble and the fourth bird

Answer (score 3):

If your whole target string is literally just `sh0rt-t3rm` then you want all that comes after the `-`.

So the barest and minimal version, cut precisely for this description, is

```
my ($capture) = $string =~ /-(.+)/;
```

We need parenthesis on the left-hand-side so to make regex run in a list [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Context) because that's when it returns the matches (otherwise it returns true/false, normally `1` or `''`).

But what if the preceding text may have `-` itself?  Then make sure to match *all* up to that last `-`

```
my ($capture) = $string =~ /.*-(.+)/;
```

Here the "greedy" nature of the `*` quantifier makes the previous `.` match all it possibly can so that the whole pattern still matches; thus it goes up until the very last `-`.

There are of course many other variations on how the data may look like, other than just being one hyphenated-word. In particular, if it's a part of a text, you may want to include word-boundaries

```
my ($capture) = $string =~ /\b.*?-(.+?)\b/;
```

Here we also need to adjust our "wild-card"-like pattern `.+` by limiting it using `?` so that it is not greedy.  This matches the first such hyphenated word in the `$string`. But if indeed only "word" characters fly then we can just use `\w` (instead of `.` and word-boundary anchors)

```
my ($capture) = $string =~ /\w*?-(\w+)/;
```

Note that `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` only, which excludes some characters that may appear in normal text (English, not to mention all other writing systems).

But this is clearly getting pickier and cookier and would need careful close inspection and testing, and more complete knowledge of what the data may look like.

Perl offers its own tutorial, [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut), and the main full reference is [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score 2):

`-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` will match a `-` followed by a word, with just the word being captured.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yBYEwn/1)

Comment: A nice  addition could be a [`\b` before](https://regex101.com/r/pH1JCa/1) to make sure being preceded by a *word character*. But I guess this has been covered in the other answers already!